# Custom HttpMessageConverters does not take precedence for String objects in Spring 3.1

Tags: spring-mvc

My Spring 3.1 project that has a custom HttpMessageConverter specified like this:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
  <mvc:message-converters>
    <bean class="myproject.MyCustomHttpMessageConverter"/>
  </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

It works, as I can convert return values marked with @ResponseBody to appropriate values. However, when the method's return value is a **String** object, my custom message converter will not be called (default converters seem to handle it, display the String as response directly).

This can be resolved if I include a **register-defaults="false"** like this:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven register-defaults="false">
  <mvc:message-converters>
    <bean class="myproject.MyCustomHttpMessageConverter"/>
  </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

This behaviour is not consistent with what is mentioned in this [blog post in springsource](http://blog.springsource.org/2011/02/21/spring-3-1-m1-mvc-namespace-enhancements-and-configuration/) that says: *"The list of message converters provided this way take priority over the message converters the MVC namespace registers by default"*.

Any idea?

Comment: Did it work if you do register-defaults="false" ?